# Dotfuscator throwing error on Xamarin.Android project on buiding solution after integration

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, dotfuscator

I followed the steps to integrate Dotfuscator into my Xamarin.Android project as described in the official documentation, but when it's time to build the project, I'm getting the following error:

> The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscatorCLI.exe" /p:InDir="obj\Release\90\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin",OutDir="obj\Release\90\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfout",ReportDir="DotfuscatorReports\Release" "DotfuscatorConfig.xml"" exited with code 1. DotfuscatorRootCheck.Android    C:\DotfuscatorRootCheck\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin_v1.5.0\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.Targets    347

I have looked and looked online, but no one seems to be having this issue. I think the problem has something to do with generating the default configuration file on the first build. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

increase the build verbosity to "Normal" as it will display a summary of the build; errors; warnings, and messages that are categorized as highly important; and the main steps of the build. (Minimal is default)

Include the error message if you see one.